Portaudio underruns for real-time input/output audio
Background:
I am making a minimal program in C++ for real-time audio I/O. I am using the portaudio library for linux (ubuntu 22.04).
My program detects the default microphone/speaker and uses them for input/output audio, respectively. This allows whatever is picked up by the microphone to be played out the speaker, in real-time.
Problem:
The program runs, but is very inconsistent in its results. Most times, it runs for a second or 2 (with no audible sound), then results in the terminal error message ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred, but continues to run. Once in a while I do get an audible sound in real-time without errors.
My code:
main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <portaudio.h>
#include <cstring>

#define SAMPLE_RATE 16000
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER 160
#define CHANNELS 1

/// @brief Handles each frame of the audio stream
/// @param inputBuffer 
/// @param outputBuffer 
/// @param framesPerBuffer 
/// @param timeInfo 
/// @param statusFlags 
/// @param userData 
/// @return integer representing status to continue
static int AudioCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData) {
    const int16_t *in = (const int16_t*)inputBuffer;
    int16_t *out = (int16_t*)outputBuffer;

    // Set output as input
    if (in != NULL) {
        memcpy(out, in, sizeof(int16_t) * framesPerBuffer);
    } else {
        memset(out, 0, sizeof(int16_t) * framesPerBuffer);
    }

    std::cout << in << " | " << out << std::endl;

    return paContinue;
}

/// @brief Handles port audio errors
/// @param err 
void PaErrorStatement(PaError err) {
    if (err != paNoError) {
        std::cout << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Redirect stderr to /dev/null to suppress PortAudio messages
    freopen("/dev/null","w",stderr);
    PaError err = Pa_Initialize();
    freopen("/dev/tty","w",stderr);
    PaErrorStatement(err);

    // Create an I/O stream
    PaStream *stream;

    // Open default input and output streams
    err = Pa_OpenDefaultStream(&stream, CHANNELS, CHANNELS, paInt16, SAMPLE_RATE, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, AudioCallback, NULL);
    PaErrorStatement(err);

    // Start audio stream
    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    PaErrorStatement(err);

    std::cout << "Recording (enter to quit)..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    // Stop stream
    err = Pa_StopStream(stream);
    PaErrorStatement(err);

    // Close stream
    err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    PaErrorStatement(err);

    // Terminate PortAudio
    err = Pa_Terminate();
    PaErrorStatement(err);
    
    return 0;
}



What I've Tried:

Debugging terminal prints

To see if audio was actually getting passed through my program, I printed out each input and output frame in the AudioCallback. The results were inconsistent, as sometimes it would run continuously without errors, sometimes it would run but throw underrun errors without recovery, and sometimes it would throw errors immediately. Below is the terminal output showing this.

Good run:
Recording (enter to quit)...
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
0x5a6496731c30 | 0x5a6496731ec0
...(continues until enter key pressed)


Bad run:
Recording (enter to quit)...
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
0x5d3159751c30 | 0x5d3159751d80
0x5d3159751c30 | 0x5d3159751d80
0x5d3159751c30 | 0x5d3159751d80
0x5d3159751c30 | 0x5d3159751d80
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
0x5d3159751c30 | 0x5d3159751d80
0x5d3159751c30 | 0x5d3159751d80
0x5d3159751c30 | 0x5d3159751d80
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Expression 'err' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3397
Expression 'ContinuePoll( self, StreamDirection_In, &pollTimeout, &pollCapture )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3948
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_WaitForFrames( stream, &framesAvail, &xrun )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4335


Bad run:
Recording (enter to quit)...
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Expression 'err' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3397
Expression 'ContinuePoll( self, StreamDirection_In, &pollTimeout, &pollCapture )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3948
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_WaitForFrames( stream, &framesAvail, &xrun )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4335




Manual I/O Assignment

I have also tried listing the available devices and manually assigning port audio to use certain ones. Example on manually assigning devices here .
Function to list devices
/// @brief Lists all I/O devices on OS
void ListDevices() {
    int numDevices = Pa_GetDeviceCount();
    if (numDevices < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Pa_GetDeviceCount returned " << numDevices << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    const PaDeviceInfo *deviceInfo;
    for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
        deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(i);
        std::cout << "Device " << i << ": " << deviceInfo->name << std::endl;
    }
}


Function call to list devices within code
// Redirect stderr to /dev/null to suppress PortAudio messages
freopen("/dev/null","w",stderr);
PaError err = Pa_Initialize();
freopen("/dev/tty","w",stderr);
PaErrorStatement(err);

ListDevices(); //CALL TO LIST DEVICES HERE

// Create an I/O stream
PaStream *stream;


Terminal output
Device 0: Intel 82801AA-ICH: - (hw:0,0)
Device 1: Intel 82801AA-ICH: MIC ADC (hw:0,1)
Device 2: front
Device 3: surround40
Device 4: pulse
Device 5: upmix
Device 6: vdownmix
Device 7: dmix
Device 8: default
Recording (enter to quit)...
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
0x55dc14d1a1c0 | 0x55dc14d1a310
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Expression 'err' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3397
Expression 'ContinuePoll( self, StreamDirection_In, &pollTimeout, &pollCapture )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3948
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_WaitForFrames( stream, &framesAvail, &xrun )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4335





My question:
I am leaning towards that this is a linux issue (since it is running on virtual box on my windows computer).

What can I do to further narrow down the issue?
Do I need to alter any audio parameters to match that of my system's mic and speaker (sample rate, channels, frames per buffer, etc.)?

Any other tips to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Have you tried without the std::cout in AudioCallback?  Otherwise, you could try increasing FRAMES_PER_BUFFER.  160 frames (10ms) might be a bit aggressive for linux non-realtime system.

@jaket Removing the std::cout statement does not change anything. I need FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 160 because the noise cancellation library I will eventually use can only support 10ms frame duration.

A 10ms IO buffer size says that the driver all the way up thru port audio and your call back has no more than 10ms to complete - not on average but every time - or you'll suffer an underflow or overflow.  If you plan to introduce processing in your callback you'll just make your problem worse.  Find a buffer size that doesn't dropout and chunk the larger IO buffers into 160 samples for the noise canceler.  For example set the buffer size to 10x160 and call the n.c. 10 times per callback.

@jaket Thank you for the tip. I implemented a larger buffer size for the stream to chunk it into smaller sizes for processing and it improved audio quality a little, but my program still stops the audio occasionally with the errors seen in my bad run: #2 above. Seems like it may be an issue more related to the ALSA sound architecture on Linux?
